# Клавиатура, кодировка и шрифт

Tags: кодировка, шрифты

Я знаю что:

1. Кодировка - это таблица связей символов и их номеров а шрифты описывают изображения символов для этих номеров символов.
2. Когда мы вводим символы с клавиатуры они записываются в файл как биты хранящие номер символа. В зависимости от кодировки эти номера разные

Вопросы:

1. На клавиатуре кнопки (и их коды) одни и теже а коды символов в разных кодировках разные. Как текстовый редактор определяет связь между клавишей и номером символа? В кодировке что хранятся номера клавиш соответствующие этим буквам?
2. Все шрифты разные и кодировки тоже  значит определённые шрифты подходят только под определённые кодировки? Или для каждого символа шрифта есть номер символа разный для каждой кодировки?

Объясните всё, пожалуйста, поподробней...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На абсолютную истину не претендую, но в целом ситуация примерно следующая:

1. Клавиатура генерирует события нажатых клавиш и отсылает код клавиши. Преобразованием в символы занимается ось (выбор языков, раскладок клавиатуры)
2. Нет связи между шрифтом и кодировкой, просто шрифт содержит в себе информацию об отображении определенных символов, т.е чисто английский шрифт неможет использоватся для отображения русских символов. логично что шрифт может покрывать/не покрывать символы с какой-то определенной кодировки. Да, код символа разный в разных кодировках.